# How to average multiple cells in same column?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to find the average for a block of data in the same column?

This is the code I was using before which wasn't working the way i had hoped for data with fewer numbers:

```
Sub Macro1() 
'Macro1 
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "" 
   'Selection.End(xlDown).Select 
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select 
   Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-13]C:R[-1]C)" 
   Selection.End(xlDown).Select 
Loop 
End Sub
```

Example: the image is the file I'm working on. I've got thousands of rows of this data and it's all separated by three blank rows. Is there a way to find the averages of each block of data and display it in the first blank row directly underneath the data?

[image]

Comment: I haven't really tried anything. I've tried googling for answer but can't find anything for what I'm looking for. I'm not too familiar with vbas, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @fishmooney every block size i.e total row for block is same?

Comment: No, some are smaller.

Comment: As @Jean-FrançoisCorbett indicated, we are more likely to help if you show us what you have tried. You can do this without needing VBA -- just appropriate Excel formulae.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (for columnA considering 3 gaps after each block including last block)

```
Sub DoAvginColumn()
Dim i as long, q as long, avgBlock
Dim lastrow as Range, firstrow as Range, rngcolA as Range, rngBlock as Range

Set lastrow = Range("A:A").Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
Set firstrow = Range("A:A").Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchDirection:=xlNext)
Set rngcolA = Range("A" & firstrow.Row & ":" & "A" & lastrow.Row)

q = 1
For i = 1 To rngcolA.Rows.Count + 1

    If rngcolA(i).Value = "" And rngcolA(i + 1).Value = "" And rngcolA(i + 2).Value = "" Then
     Set rngBlock = Range(rngcolA(q), rngcolA(i - 1))
     avgBlock = WorksheetFunction.Average(rngBlock)
     rngcolA(i).Value = avgBlock
     rngcolA(i).Font.Bold = True
     q = i + 3
    End If

Next
End Sub
```

**APPENDED**: Steps I followed: From top to bottom of respective range:

1. search for 3 consecutive blank.
2. If found, then define an appropriate range for each block starting with 1st cell of that block and ending with last cell of that block.
3. Then applied avg function on that block and put result below the block.

Comment: please comment why is this not useful?

Comment: Thanks for your help, that worked! May I ask the steps you took to getting that code?

This was the code I was using before which wasn't working the way i had hoped for data with fewer numbers:
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
'
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-13]C:R[-1]C)"
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    
Loop
End Sub

Comment: @fishmooney you can delete the code from comment as I added that to your question. And see appended answer for the steps I took. Anyway, could you pls upvote it, cause someone else downvoted earlier without stating reason and its bugging me.